# IE-only Styling for jQuery qTip

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I'm using jquery.qTip on http://comps.gunnjerkens.com/phws/services/

Looks beautiful with the drop shadow and rounded borders in modern browsers...unfortunately the drop shadow is lost on IE. So I want to specify an IE-only rule that makes the border a different color than white. Here's how I currently have it setup:

```
$(this).qtip({
    content: the_content,
    position: {
        corner: {
            target: 'bottomLeft',
            tooltip: 'topLeft'
        },
        adjust: {
            screen: true
        }
    },
    style: {
        border: {
            radius: 4,
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        color: '#7D9240'
    }
});
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Damn the code looked fine in the editor, what happened? Oh well hopefully you get the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color: $.browser.msie ? '#someothercolor : '#FFFFFF'` will let you define a different color. Note this is an old deperecated way to check browser version read up on the up to date methods in the jquery docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hate to have to check for a user-agent, but sometimes you have to make some compromises to satisfy the client...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

Not sure if it's a .png IE6 issue you're having but you'd load it specifically for that browser with this in the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/belatedpng_0.0.8a.js">
<![endif]-->
```